# Make copies of clone element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `input` which has some functionality on it. In some case I am receiving a `array` which contains predefined `input` `value` then I have to append that `input` list using that array. The the problem is only one input field is created. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gggd5yp/)

```
    $('.row input').click(function() {
        alert(0)
    })

    var data = $('#myList').clone(true);
    $('.row').remove()

    var list = ['car', 'axe', 'gold'];
    $.each(list, function(i, val) {
        $('#myList').prepend(data.find('input').val(val))
    })
```

**Note:** Also the functionality which is attached to `input` is defined somewhere in another `js` file and I could not change it. It would break other pages

Comment: Is requirement to clone, prepend `#myList` element , or `input` element within `#myList` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are cloning the `#myList` element. It has  one `input` descendant. After the first iteration the cloned `div` doesn't have any `input` descendant so the next `find` calls return an empty collection and the `prepend` method effectively doesn't do anything. One option is:

```
var $input = $('#myList').find('input').detach();
$('.row').remove();

var list = ['car', 'axe', 'gold'];
$.each(list, function (i, val) {
    $('#myList').prepend($input.clone(true).val(val));
});
```

The above snippet instead of *moving* the input element, clones it and prepends the cloned element to the container.

**edit**: You can pass a collection of elements to the `.prepend()` method. When you pass nodes to the method it doesn't clone and prepend them, it only *moves* them and a node can't be a child of 2 parent elements, so using `.clone()` is necessary in this case. This is what happens in your original code:

```
var data = $('#myList').clone(true);
// ...
$.each(list, function (i, val) {
    console.log( 'index: ' + i + ', html: ' + data.html() );
    $('#myList').prepend(data.find('input').val(val))
});
```

Logged data:

```
index: 0, html: 
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>add row</button>
    </div>

index: 1, html: 
    <div class="row">

    </div>
    <div>
        <button>add row</button>
    </div>

index: 2, html: 
    <div class="row">

    </div>
    <div>
        <button>add row</button>
    </div>
```

As you can see after the first iteration the wrapper element no longer has any `input` descendant. Having 1 or many elements doesn't affect the result. In the first iteration all the `input` descendants returned by the `find` method are *moved* into the target element.

Comment: Thanks its works. this is the code which I need $input.clone(true)

Comment: "After the first iteration the cloned div doesn't have any input descendant". Can you please elaborate this.